# Advice on learning about web applications

Tags: database

I know how to write programs in Java and C++, and would like to learn how servers, databases and Internet based applications work so I could start developing them.

Where should I start? What should I learn first? What books would you recommend for me?

Thank you, in advance :)

Comment: i'm not that dumb :D in fact, i'm rather experienced computer/internet user, and i still know nothing about how all this stuff works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by either trying [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) which would let you create fairly basic web applications. I would start by playing around with either servlettes or JSPs. There is a lot documentation and examples.

Or you could start by downloading and playing around with a database. [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) is really good. It is free and they have a tool called pgadmin which is a really good ide.

Once you have been able to get these set up and working I would then start taking a look at some various frameworks that exist to make using these tools a lot easier. For example, you could take a look at [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) or [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) for dependency injection or a range of other tools.  [This](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/SpringComparison) is a comparison of each.

You will also probably want to also look into [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/), [Freemarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/), or [struts](http://struts.apache.org/), or something similar. These will make your life a lot easier.

For the database you could look at: [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) or [MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org/), both are really good and function slightly differentially. Hibernate is very commonly used and they [cache objects](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/37-introduction-to-hibernate-caching-1.html) very efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "cells", anyway you may start from open source technologies and their online docs, like [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/),  [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index.html), and [PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/).